# Tracing a pont on an animated object

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

I recently tried to make some simple animations of some 3d objects by using Location and Location/Rotation keyframes. In the end I noticed that the movements are not very smooth, so I started skimming through the frames to see which keyframe must be adjusted. So I thought it would be really nice to see the path of the object as e.g. a 3d curve. I found the *curve editor* but this is a little bit hard to read as each variable of the keyframes is plotted separately.

Is it possible to view the trace of some defined point (or even if it is just the origin) of an animated object such that you see  the whole path it travels throughout the animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your object, set the frame range you want to visualize, and press calculate or update path in the motion path tab of the properties window. It works with bones also.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for! I tried it now (successfully) and in order to visualize the path of some point other than the origin, I just added a new object at the desired location, parented it to the main object but then displayed the path of the new object. Do you know of an easier way to do this?

Comment: Yours is quite easy!

Comment: If the object bothers you, add a little empty.

Comment: Oh I didn't know about *empties*, thanks a lot!